# Send User Identity to SQL for login

Tags: c#, sql-server, iis-7, connection-string, application-pool

We have developed a product which is a **web application**. While configuring it in IIS, we disable all the authentication modes except **Windows authentication** (app works on Windows authentication only).

We create a service account and provide admin access to that account on all the servers, and on database servers.

We configure the connection string in `web.config` with username and password of that service account. Everything was working fine till now.

We received a new requirement which says, no service account will be created and individual users will be granted database access. We have to configure our application in such a way that Windows credentials are used to access the app gets passed to SQL Server. Reason for this change: we can log the user accessing the database.

I set `Integrated Security=SSPI` in the connection string and tried with different App Pool Identity but to no avail.

We are even ready to change the code if same is required to achieve the functionality.

Can someone please help me what am I missing, or how it can be achieved? Please let me know if more information is required and I will be happy to provide the same.

App server and database server are on the same domain and network but different machines. Users accessing the application will be on the same domain and network. This is a intranet based application.

Comment: What is the error you are getting with Integrated security?

Comment: Can not access the Database using "Anonymous", "SERVER_NAME$", "APP_POOL_IDENTITY" depending on which Identity is set in App Pool configuration

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable and configure constrained delegation. Follow this document: [How to Implement Kerberos Constrained Delegation with SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg723715.aspx). Your app pool need to be configured to impersonate, see [Using IIS Authentication with ASP.NET Impersonation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/134ec8tc.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Remus, let me try and I will update once done.

Answer (score 0):

Also this will be a hop scenario so you will have to enable delegation for the IIS server and if you intend to pass user credentials then you need to enable delegation for the user accounts too. You can use the tool delegconfig to troubleshoot this.